# Angular refresh google api token

Tags: angular, google-drive-api, access-token

I need to extend or refresh token, becouse now is 3600 seconds.
I'm tring to understand how is better using access grant offline or refresh_token

Answer (score 1):

The access_type, which is usually set to be `online` per default, defines whether the user needs to be present in order to refresh the access token. As explained in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect):

> The allowed values are offline and online. The effect is documented in [Offline Access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline); if an access token is being requested, the client does not receive a refresh token unless offline is specified.

In order to grant offline access to your application, you can use the `GoogleAuth.grantOfflineAccess` ([See here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthgrantofflineaccessoptions)) instead of `GoogleAuth.signIn()`.

Following [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js?hl=id) Javascript client API Quickstart for google sheets, the only code modification would be in the `handleAuthClick()` function as follows:

```js
function handleAuthClick(event) {
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().grantOfflineAccess({scope: SCOPES});
}
```

This is not a feature that is used much often for client-side applications, since they are usually short-lived. These applications often let the access token expire and then prompt the user again with the login. However, by setting this parameter to offline you can get the refresh token and avoid having to prompt the user every 1 hour. It is up to you and your application's needs.